# Why wont my variable increment by another specified variable inside a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, increment

I have two slightly different variations of the same application, which models a system of chemical reactions over a certain period calculating the changes in the number of molecules of each reactant as a reaction fires.

The code is meant to start the simulation at a start time, tao, then increase tao by specified time step, delta_t, in the first of the two while loops below it works properly. tao increases by delta_t with each iteration of the loop. But in the second for some reason the start time of the simulation, tao, isn't increased by delta_t.

```
while tao < tmax:
    propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)        
    a0 = (sum(propensity))
    if a0 == 0.0:
        break
    lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t)
    rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam)    
    if tao + delta_t > tmax:
        break
    tao += delta_t  
    for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):
        state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
        popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda
    new_propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)    
    for m in range(len(propensity)):
        for n in range(len(new_propensity)):
            propensity_check = propensity[m] + state_change_lambda
            if propensity_check[m] - new_propensity[n] >= a0:  
                print("The value of delta_t {} choosen is too large".format(delta_t))
                break
            else:
                # check if any num in popul_num is negative must stop simulation and reject leap
                if popul_num.any() < 0:
                    break   
                popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
```

^^^first snippet that works properly increasing tao by delta_t after each iteration

```
while tao < tmax:
    propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)        
    a0 = (sum(propensity))  # a0 is a numpy.float64
    if a0 == 0.0 or popul_num.any() < 0:
        break   # if reaction cannot fire corresponding element in rxn_vector should be zero --> tau leaping method 
    lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t) 
    rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam) # probability of a reaction firing in the given time period
    tao += delta_t     # not updating tao and only doing one leap!     
    if tao + delta_t > tmax:
        break 
    else:   # otherwise...
        if tao >= 2/a0:     # if tao is big enough
            for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):  
                state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
                new_propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)  
                propensity_check = propensity.copy()
                propensity_check[0] += state_change_lambda[0]
                propensity_check[1:] += state_change_lambda 
                leap_check = propensity_check - new_propensity
                for n in range(len(leap_check)): # post leap propensity check
                    if leap_check[n] >= epsi*a0:   
                        print("The value of delta_t {} choosen is too large".format(delta_t))
                        break  
                    else:
                        popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda                  
                        popul_num_all.append(popul_num) # indentation of this determines how far x-axis goes? 
        else:
            t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
            rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
            num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
            if tao + t > tmax:      
                tao = tmax
                break
            j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs() 
            tao = tao + t
            popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))  
            print("Simulation time:\n", t, tao)
            popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
    leap_counter = tao / delta_t    # divide tao by delta_t to calculate number of leaps
```

^^^Second snippet that doesn't increase the value of tao by delta_t after each iteration.

I cant get my head around whats changed between the two pieces of code and why the second doesn't increase tao? Any suggestions?

Comment: Surely after switching those lines, you need to check only whether `tao` is greater than `tmax`, not `tao + delta_t`. Also, of course it's increasing `tao`, that's what that statement does. What makes you think it's not increasing it? You print it before and after the statement?

Comment: Where is tao initialized?  I'm suspecting that maybe the initialization of tao also got moved to an outer scope causing a scoping issue with two different variables named tao.

Comment: Yeah printing tao after the loop only prints the intialised value of delta_t. Tao and delta_t are both initialised outside of my while for both code snippets, should I move them to inside the while loop?

Comment: not inside the loop.  However, tao needs to be initialized and printed afterwards in the same function.